# List *next pointer isn't pointing to another node, returning 3221226356

Tags: c, linked-list

I'm working in a function to read a .geo file, saving its contents in a linked list. The problem lies when i fill a node and have to create another and then make the next pointer points to the new node.

The function calls an empty linked list (ola), which *next pointer points to null.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct cel{
    char *nome;
    char *borda;
    char *meio;
    double x;
    double y;
    
    double lar;
    double alt; 
    
    struct cel * next;
    
} celula;

void ler(celula * ola){
    celula * aux = ola;
    char comando[30];
    char borda[20] = "transparent";
    char meio[20] = "transparent";
    FILE *fp;
    fp = fopen("c-rects.geo", "r");
    int b;
    double i;
    
    for (b=0; b<50;b++){    
        fscanf(fp, "%s", comando);
        if(!strcmp(comando, "nx")){
            fscanf(fp, "%lf", &i);
            fscanf(fp, "%lf", &i);
            fscanf(fp, "%lf", &i);
            fscanf(fp, "%lf", &i);
            fscanf(fp, "%lf", &i);
        }   
        else if(!strcmp(comando, "r")){
            fscanf(fp, "%s", aux->nome);
            aux->borda = borda;
            aux->meio = meio;
            fscanf(fp, "%lf", &aux->x);
            fscanf(fp, "%lf", &aux->x);
            fscanf(fp, "%lf", &aux->y);
            fscanf(fp, "%lf", &aux->lar);
            fscanf(fp, "%lf", &aux->alt);
            
        }
        else if(!strcmp(comando, "cc")){
            fscanf(fp, "%s", meio);
        }
        else if(!strcmp(comando, "cp")){
            fscanf(fp, "%s", borda);
        }
    
        aux->next = (celula *) malloc(sizeof(celula));
        aux = aux->next;
        aux->next = NULL;
}
    

}
```

Example input:

```
nx 110 1000 1000 1000 1000
 
cp tan cc gold 

r r_269.00-686.00-1.0-15.0 269.000000 686.000000 1.000000 15.000000
```

Name should be r_269.00-686.00-1.0-15.0

Borda: gold

Meio: tan

X: 269.000000

Y: 686.000000

lar: 1.000000

alt: 15.000000

Should be working fine, no idea why it doesn't work only in this situation.

Comment: There's a lot of problems here but the main one is storing a pointer to `borda` and `meio` in the list. Those arrays stop existing  when `ler` returns because they are local variables inside `ler` .

Comment: @M.M the char pointer to borda/meia in the list is supposed to store a string, i'm not sure if i can use a char array inside of a list.

Comment: Please post an [mcve].

Comment: You _could_ add `static` to `borda` and `meio`. That might be the quick fix. If you _only_ set `aux->borda = borda; aux->meio = meio;` (i.e. a given `struct` instance only has these values or `NULL`). But, you should initialize them to `NULL` (e.g. `aux->borda = NULL; aux->meio = NULL;`) Note: you _may_ be allocating one too many struct instances.

Comment: Please _edit_ your question and put your sample input file data in a separate code block [vs. just adding it in a comment].

Comment: @CraigEstey: with using `static`, each member of linked list would points to the same `borda` or `maio`. If a new `borda` or `maio` is read, values change in all members of the linked list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are probably several problems. But not all code is shown, main is missing.
**Typical main problem in your code** is that memory is not allocated.

Make sure that you properly allocate memory to the pointers (`malloc`). **Note: the allocated memory for local variables in subroutine `ler` is lost, after subroutine `ler` is left.** Take care to allocate memory for the structure `cel` as well, e.g. in main routine. You need to work-through the whole code to check for this. (Then you also read about free memory, but you might not need it here, command `free`)

One possible step forward is shown below: `cel` already includes memory for `nome`, `borda` and `meio`. But that is not all, you really need to understand the problem and fix it through-out the code.

```
typedef struct cel{
    char nome[30];
    char borda[30];
    char meio[30];
    double x;
    double y;
    
    double lar;
    double alt; 
    
    struct cel *next;
    
} celula;
```

Comment: Should i use a strcpy to pass the strings from function to the list?

Comment: `strgcpy` could be part of a solution, INSTEAD of copying the pointer `aux->borda = borda;`, you could copy the value(string) into your structure, e.g. by `strgcpy`.

Comment: Did you allocate memory in `main` for the first node?

Comment: Noticed i just forgot a line in the middle of the code while testing and it messed it all. Actually it's working fine.

Comment: Great to hear that you were able to solve the problem that quickly! If there were any useful answers or comments which helped you to solve the problem, then don't forget to vote.

Answer (score 0):

There are some issues ...

`meio` and `borda` are function scoped variables. When setting them into a `celula` instance, we need to use `strdup`.

Likewise, for `nome`.

We can make the sizes of these a bit larger.

Only allocate an instance with `malloc` for the `r` command. Otherwise, there are a lot of empty/garbage entries.

Better to have `ler` allocate and return a pointer to the linked list, so we should change the prototype.

In `ler`, we need `fclose(fp)`

---

Here's some refactored code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct cel {
    char *nome;
    char *borda;
    char *meio;
    double x;
    double y;

    double lar;
    double alt;

    struct cel *next;

} celula;

celula *
ler(void)
{
    celula *ola = NULL;
    celula *prev = NULL;
    celula *aux = NULL;
    char comando[30];
    char borda[200] = "transparent";
    char meio[200] = "transparent";
    char nome[200];
    FILE *fp;

    fp = fopen("c-rects.geo", "r");
    int b;
    double i;

    for (b = 0; b < 50; b++) {
        if (fscanf(fp, "%s", comando) != 1)
            break;

        if (!strcmp(comando, "nx")) {
            fscanf(fp, "%lf", &i);
            fscanf(fp, "%lf", &i);
            fscanf(fp, "%lf", &i);
            fscanf(fp, "%lf", &i);
            fscanf(fp, "%lf", &i);
        }

        else if (!strcmp(comando, "r")) {
            prev = aux;

            aux = malloc(sizeof(*aux));
            aux->next = NULL;

            if (ola == NULL)
                ola = aux;

            if (prev != NULL)
                prev->next = aux;

            aux->borda = strdup(borda);
            aux->meio = strdup(meio);

            fscanf(fp, "%s", nome);
            aux->nome = strdup(nome);

            fscanf(fp, "%lf", &aux->x);
            fscanf(fp, "%lf", &aux->x);
            fscanf(fp, "%lf", &aux->y);
            fscanf(fp, "%lf", &aux->lar);
            fscanf(fp, "%lf", &aux->alt);

        }
        else if (!strcmp(comando, "cc")) {
            fscanf(fp, "%s", meio);
        }
        else if (!strcmp(comando, "cp")) {
            fscanf(fp, "%s", borda);
        }
    }

    fclose(fp);

    return ola;
}
```